# How to handle page redirection when loading local html file?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

In my HTML file:

```html
<div data-role="content" id="termsContent">
    <div id="termDiv"></div>
</div>
```

in my js file:

```js
$(function () {
    $("#termsPage").live('pagecreate', function(event,ui){
        $("#termDiv").load("tnc.html").trigger('create');
    });
});
```

Then, in my tnc.html file:

```html
<a href="http://www.xxx.com/usage-terms.html">
```

I seem can't find any solution in Google on how to load the local html page correctly. Does anyone have suggestion/experience on this? I want to show the clicked link directly.

Comment: Again, do you want to load it and use it later or do you want to load it and show it at a same time?

Comment: hi Gajotres, sorry I need to delete the other thread.. I want to load and show it after clicking the link.. Any suggestion?

Comment: No problem, I will create you working example.

Answer (score 0):

You were close but not enough.

1. .trigger('create') can not be used after a load function. Load function is asynchronous so we need to wait for success state to trigger pagecreate.
2. Button example is not going to be shown, it needs to be closed.
3. Do not use **pagecreate**, in this case **pagebeforeshow**

Here's a working example:

**index.html :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>        
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
            <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
                    <div id="termDiv">

                    </div>
        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

**load.html :**

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" data-role="button" rel="external">Onen link</a>
```

**index.js :**

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    $("#termDiv").load("load.html", function(){
        $('#index').trigger('create');
    });  
});
```

I hope this was what you wanted all along.

Comment: thx Gajotres, I will try this tomorrow and hopefully there will be a good news.. Sorry can't give any now because I quite new in JQuery Mobile, so I can't get full understanding of your code without trying it :)